# HTML5 input color's default color

Tags: html, input, colors

The `input type="color"` has a default color which is black: `#000000`.

Even if I give it an empty value...

`<input type="color" value="" />`

...the default color is always black.

I want the user to have the option of picking a color, but if he doesn't it means no color was picked, not even white `#FFFFFF`.

Is there a way to force an `input type="color"` not to have black color as default?

I can use some kind of a "listener" to check if the user changed the color for the first time, if not, ignore the value, but I would like to avoid Javascript.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you want as the default input color?

Comment: @PankajParashar NULL, just like when you have an `<input type="text"/>` and it has no value. HTML5 forces `<input type="color"/>` to have a default color which is black, I need it to have a NULL value, means, no color is selected.

Comment: Understood your question now. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have updated my answer now with a possible workaround :)

Comment: Looks like in Chrome, you can specify `value="#"` and it will return that (`#`) on submitting the form.

Comment: Excuse me if I come over blunt, but your workaround is not useful IMO, Pankaj.
IMO the important thing is the value that is POSTed, which is always a value (#000000 default). Tested in Firefox.

Answer (score 29):

While using hexcode for `value` attribute in `<input type="color">`, one thing I noticed is that it has to be six digits, if for white you use `#fff`, it does not work. It has to be `#ffffff`.

The same thing happens when setting it through javascript.
`document.querySelector('input[type="color"]').value = '#fff'` does not work. The color remains black.
You have to use `document.querySelector('input[type="color"]').value = '#ffffff'` for it to work.

Something to be careful about.

Comment: Yes that is because the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.color.html) defines that the `value` attribute must contain exactly 7 characters, starting with `#` and then followed by 6  hexadecimal characters. Infact color keywords like `red`, `blue` are also not allowed.

Answer (score 8):

Use value:

```
<input type="color" value="#ff00ff" />
```

If you want to know if input remain unchanged, you can do something like this (with jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    $('input').change(function(){
       $(this).addClass('changed');
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3hZB/

Comment: But what if the user does likes the predetermined color, and thus leaves it the way it is?
It does not mean the user did not pick a color, just that he likes it the way it is.

Comment: Well then input won't get 'changed' class, you must use that fact as non-pick state.

Comment: Understood. Though if you had a form like this:

Your Favorite Color: `color input`,

Your Favorite Food: `text input`,

Etc.

and the users favorite color was already selected, your script would leave the users favorite color in an undecided state.

Comment: And that's what happen when you try use regular input for fancy forms :) It always requires some additional checkboxes etc. Similar problem with radio buttons, once you chose one, you cannot set unchecked state.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution, switching input type from text to color:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dc-color-input-switcher', function() {
  var dcInputColor = $(this).parent().parent().prev();
  if (dcInputColor.attr('type') == 'text') {
    dcInputColor.attr('type', 'color');
  } else {
    dcInputColor.attr('type', 'text');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.dc-color-input-clearer', function() {
  var dcInputColor2 = $(this).parent().parent().next();
  if (dcInputColor2.attr('type') == 'color') {
    dcInputColor2.attr('type', 'text');
  }
  dcInputColor2.val('');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <span title="Empty" class="btn btn-danger dc-color-input-clearer" data-original-title="Empty Field"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input name="product_tabs[1][0][bg_color]" value="" placeholder="Background Color" class="form-control pre-input-color" type="text">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <span title="Toggle color picker" class="btn btn-primary dc-color-input-switcher" data-original-title="Switch color picker"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for older jQuery with "cannot change type" error: $(this).parent().parent().prev()[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');$(this).parent().parent().prev().val('');

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** Now since, I have understood your question correctly, I have updated my answer.

Although the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.color.html) defines that the `value` attribute has a string representing the color, it doesn't define the default color. So I think that the implementation of default color is left at the discretion of the browser.

However, the [WhatWG Spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#color-state-(type=color)) anwers your question with this note,

> **Note:** When the input type element is in the color state, there is always a color picked, and there is no way to set the value to the empty string.

Moreover, based on your expectation, the CSS language never defined a `NULL` attribute for any element, which makes it impossible for the `input type='color'` to have `NULL` as the default value.

**Workaround:**

The workaround is present in the  Shadow DOM API.

[image]

Using Chrome Developer Tools, I found that we can give a `transparent` color to the pseudo element `::-webkit-color-swatch` background property -

```
input[type=color]::-webkit-color-swatch 
{ 
    background-color: transparent !important; 
}
```

For the above CSS, your HTML should like this - `<input type="color">`. Now you don't need to have any kind of listener to tell if the user has changed the default color or not. You can simply treat the `transparent` color as the NULL color based on which you can make a decision whether the value was changed or not!

I am sure that you will find similar kind of information from the Shadow DOM for Firefox to set transparent value for background. IE still remains a pain for us.

Comment: It is always transparent even after selecting a color

Comment: This is only a solution for appearance, not for POSTed values. If this input type is submitted in a form there is no way of knowing if a user has chosen a color or not.
By the way, the same holds for the range input type, where the value attribute is also chosen as 'holder' for the default value. IMO this is not properly thought through. But I could be wrong. Rather still, I hope so. Because now these types of input are almost useless for me

Comment: @JPA: I have also encountered many situations where the end user inability to select "not defined" is a big problem. I haven't found a good workaround. The closest I can do with existing HTML5 controls is to prepend all such controls with a radio button with options "Use default / Not set" and "Custom value:".

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be twofold.

1. For display purposes, yes, you can set a default color just by setting the value of the input to the color you want. You can see varieties of this in the answers on this page.
2. Technically, no. It is not possible to send an empty value as color through POST. The POSTed value will always default to `#000000` or the color which you have set default (as mentioned in 1.).

---

*After some thought on this, perhaps a practical solution for this might be to choose `#010101` as a reference to `null` or `false` or whatever. This leaves room for some jQuery (or javascript) to make it less likely that this value can be set.*

```
<input type="color" name="myColor" required="" />
```

*For instance, on one hand the color inputs that are set to `required` can be given the value `#010101` at event `load`. And to be sure, prevent users selecting the color #010101.*

```
(function($){

  "use strict";

  // Set all required color input values to #010101.
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    $("[type='color'][required]").val() == "#010101";
  });

  $("[type='color'][required]").on("change", function() {

    // Prevent users selecting the color #010101.
    if($(this).val() == "#010101") {
      $(this).val() == "#000000";
    }
  });

})(jQuery)
```

*At the time of server-side validation, `#010101` is considered as `empty` (or `false`, etc.).*

```
<?php
$color = htmlspecialchars($_POST['myColor']);
if($color == "#010101") {
  // Do variable empty routine
} else {
  // Do variable has value routine
}
?>
```

*Now you can be pretty sure to know if the user has set the value, as long as the UA has javascript capabilities.

The drawback is the setting of the color on load. Reload with a pre-set value is not possible this way. Perhaps this can be improved with the use of sessionStorage.*

*But the real point is: Why am I doing this? I don't think it should be neccessary, the default value of `#000000` is **the single deviation** from the normal workings of an input type. Except for the `range` input type, which also has an optional default value, this color input type is very different.*

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this issue is only available on chrome, but I just found the quick fix for chrome. We need to set the input value to #FFFFFF first and after that set it to default value, the default color will appear instead of black

```
var element = document.querySelector('input[type="color"]');
element.value = '#FFFFFF'; //remember the hex value must has 7 characters
element.value = element.defaultValue;
```

Hope it help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for setting a different default color from black:

```
   <input
        type="color"
        value="#123456"
        onChange={(e) => handleBGColor(e)}
    ></input>
```

However when I was using shorthand 3-hex values like "#000" or "#FFF" instead of 6 like above it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this kind of solution for myself. It displays nice "transparent" button. When clicked it triggers the normal hidden input-color. When color is picked up, the transparent button will hide and the input-color will show up.

Cheers.

```js
function clickInputColor( button )
{
 $( button ).next().click();
}

function inputColorClicked( input )
{
 $( input ).show();
 $( input ).prev().hide();
}
```

```css
.inputEmptyColorButton {
 background:url("http://vickcreator.com/panel/images/transparent.png") center repeat;
 width: 50px;
 height: 1.5em;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 border: 1px solid #666;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="clickInputColor( this );" class="inputEmptyColorButton"></button>
     <input onchange="inputColorClicked( this );" style="display: none;" type="color" value="" />
```