# HTML5 input type color: set no color / delete color

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

Simple question:

(How) is it possible to set the value of an `<input type="color">` to empty in the colorpicker when selecting such an input in Chrome?

*Edit: I want to change the input's value to `""`*

Comment: What do you mean by "empty?"

Comment: You could use JavaScript

Comment: If the input value is "empty" what does the color picker is supposed to show?

Comment: @L105 I thought the color picker could provide an option to have no color. Similar to e.g. Word where you often have the option to choose "no color" in a color picker. I guess the Chrome color picker is not adjustable though, right?

Answer (score 4):

I think it cannot be set to be `transparent`, but you can modify the start color with `value="#colorhex"`.

For example;

```
<input type="color" value="#0000ff">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3hZB/4/

Edit: It seems that when `input` has `type="color"` there is always a color defined, and there's no way to set that string to empty.

Although here, [the guy with second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943074/html5-input-colors-default-color) says he figured out a workaround.